# Document Store and search

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, database, nosql

I need to have a storage mechanism for storing large number of documents ( word , pdf etc ) 
The documents mostly will be scanned copies or manuals with diagrams.
The scanned copies are critical and reliability is important.

I am planning to use No-SQL DB for the same ( currently share point is being used which I am planning to get rid of ) 
Search functionality on the contents of the document is an added advantage.

Based on some evaluation , I feel NOSQL DB with a search engine can address the problem. 
If anybody has done any implementation of this sort or have some other ideas  , please revert back

Comment: I would rather suggest you to use Apache Solr search engine which provides sublime NoSQL search cum database capabilities. MongoDB and Cassandra are datastores and I don't think people using it extensively for search functionality. Apache Solr is a proven NoSQL search engine and could be the right choice for you.

Comment: There is an enterprise version of Cassandra, called DSE Search, that provides Cassandra as storage and Solr for the search capabilities. Unfortunately it's not open source ...

Comment: Thanks both of you. I will evaluate apache solr and DSE search against my requirement

Comment: In case if the search functionality is not needed , and I need to store only documents , then which noSQL would be the best option ?